# My project does not seem to recognize struts.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

**`/WEB-INF/web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="MyStrutsApp" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I put `struts.xml` under `src` and set it in `web.xm`l, but I get 404 error only.

[image]

Comment: Use `<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />` in `struts.xml` to enable logging errors.

Comment: The `struts.xml` file, by default, is expected to be at the root of your app's classpath, not in `WEB-INF`. Look to see how it's deployed.

Comment: If you can't follow the tutorial then choose another one.